# alternative to pageant for Git when TortoiseGit is installed

Tags: windows, tortoisegit, ssh-agent, pageant

I have TortoiseGit and Git for windows installed.
I can successfully clone a repository with the SSH protocol and a private and public key if I use pageant, but what shall I do if I don't want to use pageant?
I have in my %HOME% directory my pair of keys in .ssh/id_rsa and ./ssh/id_rsa.pub
I have a script which starts ssh-agent when I start Git-bash for the first time but when I try to clone something it pops up with
TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error
In settings for TortoiseGit I have for SSH client
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe

Answer (score 0):

Don't use settings in the config dialog window instead use the wizard in the end of installation of the tortoisegit